# Python: Import from variable after finding all files in dir

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a python program for a given software than will scan&run another certain python function at choice *(or .py file altogether)*. However I can't `import` a function name set in a variable.

```
import glob

functions_list = glob.glob('*.py')
#all my python files are found
#pick any specific file to import
import a[3]
```

This fails with `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Is there any way to do this?
My idea is to have a TkInter selection list where I click to run the .py I selected.

Answer (score 1):

Why not run the script inside a subprocess using a shell command?

```
subprocess.call(['python', a[3])
```

See here for more info:
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/subprocess-for-system-administrators

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at python's [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) module. It enables you to dynamically load modules at runtime and then execute their functions.

Comment: This has been deprecated since 3.4, one should use `importlib` instead

Comment: fp, pathname, desc = imp.find_module(a[0].strip('.py'))  /n imp.load_module(a[0].strip('.py'),fp,pathname,desc) /n This worked